# Improve simulation speed using Compile

Tags: matrix, compile

I have two square matrices, a hermitian matrix    h and an unitary matrix    v. I am interested in the following function

```
step[h_,v_,n_]:=Map[Tr,Dot[NestList[MatrixExp[-I h].#.MatrixExp[I h]&,v,n-1],v]];
```

which generates a list of n real numbers. The dimensions of the matrices are not so big so `MatrixExp` is still quite efficient. I want to make the above function faster by using `Compile`,

```
stepcp:=Compile[{{m,_Complex,2},{v,_Complex,2},{n,_Integer}}, Map[Tr,Dot[NestList[m.#.ConjugateTranspose[m]&,v,n-1],v]]];
```

The compiled version is only a few times faster than the uncompiled version. As an example

```
l = 128;
v = KroneckerProduct[SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1., {2, 2} -> -1.}],SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> 1., l]];
h := 1/2 ArrayFlatten[{{PadLeft[1/2 SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> 1., Band[{2, 1}] -> -1.}, l], {l, 2 l}]}, {PadRight[-(1/2)SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> 1., Band[{2, 1}] -> -1.}, l], {l, 2 l}]}}] + 1/2 KroneckerProduct[SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1., {2, 2} -> -1.}, 2],DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Table[RandomReal[{-1., 1.}], {j, l}]]]];

step[m_, u_, n_] := 1/(2 l) Map[Tr,Dot[NestList[MatrixExp[-I m].#.MatrixExp[I m] &, v, n - 1],v]]; 
stepcp := Compile[{{m, _Complex, 2}, {u, _Complex, 2}, {n, _Integer}},1./(2 l) Map[Tr,Dot[NestList[m.#.ConjugateTranspose[m] &, u, n - 1], u]]];

step[h, v, 64]; // AbsoluteTiming
stepcp[Normal[MatrixExp[-I h]], Normal[v], 64]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

My questions are:

1. How to compile this function more efficiently?
2. The matrices    h and    v are    SparseArray, why can't I directly pass them into compiled functions, why do I have to use    Normal[]?
3. The    CompilePrint is shown below, is the    MainEvaluate in line 1 and 29 a source of slowdown, if so can it be circumvented?

[image]

My eventual goal is to run an efficiently compiled version of    step[h,v,n] 10000 times and take the    Mean. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you mis-spelled `NestList`; also the function that returns the complex conjugate is simply `Conjugate` in *Mathematica*. Or have you redefined those function? If so you should give us your definition.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say ConjugateTranspose, I have corrected it

Comment: I don't get the same CompilePrint output as you do. In particular, you seem to have defined two arguments in your posted function, and yet your CompilePrint output indicates 4 arguments. Are you sure that the code you posted exactly corresponds to your working code? Also, why is $n$ not an argument to your compiled function?

Comment: Sorry, I have added an example and re-uploaded the corresponding compileprint.

Comment: Look, do yourself a favor: go over your code VERY carefully, and post ONE version of your function that you want to troubleshoot, with the corresponding `CompilePrint` output. It's very hard to hit a moving target. Your question won't attract many answers if you post incomplete and inconsistent code. Furthermore, the second version of your function, in context, contains a parameter $l$ that the first version of the function does not contain. You should include that parameter in the function definition as well.

Comment: I have rearranged the post, perhaps it's clearer now. I apologize for the inconsistencies presented in earlier posts.

Comment: Your question is nice (I didn't see the earlier revisions). But compilation will generally not gain you anything for most linear algebra functions, which are just library calls anyway. Compilation is mainly useful for procedural code. You should probably look at other (algorithmic) ways to optimize the code, such as [the approach presented by Simon Woods](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84217/) below. Compilation could then be useful if this causes you to adopt a more procedural approach, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives a slight speed up (~40%) for me:

```
stepcp = Compile[{{m, _Complex, 2}, {u, _Complex, 2}, {n, _Integer}, {l, _Real}},
  Block[{
    m2 = ConjugateTranspose@m, x = u, ut = Flatten@Transpose@u},
   Join[{1.0}, Table[x = m.x.m2; Flatten[x].ut, {i, n - 1}]/(2 l)]]]
```

I replaced the `NestList` with a more procedural approach, calculating the trace of the dot product at each step using the relation `Tr[a.b] == Flatten[a].Flatten[Transpose[b]]`

I also put `l` in as an argument - there's no real performance increase as a result but I find it neater than having a callback to the main evaluator.

Oleksandr R. points out that the run time is dominated by calls to the math library so compilation is not really helping much. In fact almost all the gain you got from the compiled version versus the original was due to not computing `MatrixExp` at each step. You get almost the same speed with this:

```
step[m_, u_, n_, l_] :=
 With[{m1 = MatrixExp[-I m], m2 = MatrixExp[I m]}, 
  1/(2 l) Map[Tr, Dot[NestList[m1.#.m2 &, v, n - 1], v]]]
```

Comment: I find that compilation hardly helps here. With or without it, the run time seems to be completely dominated by MKL calls.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you elaborate a bit more on why using a procedural approach is better here? @Simon Woods

Comment: @user64620, I needed to use an explicit loop so that I could compute the trace at each step. Since `Compile` translates `NestList` into a procedural loop anyway (as you can see from the `CompilePrint` output), there's nothing to lose from writing it that way.

Comment: @user64620, More generally, I find it useful to have the *Mathematica* code closely reflect the compiled instructions, so that I can understand better what the compiler is doing. Sometimes you can spot optimisations more easily that way. Though as Oleksandr pointed out, it makes little difference for this problem since all the time is spent doing the dot products.

Answer (score 2):

1. Sorry, I don't know.  Have you tried compiling to C?  One point: you should define `stepcp` with [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) (`=`) rather than [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) or you recompile it every time you use it.
2. `SparseArray` is a specialized format of the high-level *Mathematica* language.  It is not supported by compilation.  Many operations are optimized to work on sparse arrays, saving unnecessary computation, which may be why your uncompiled method is proportionately faster than you expect.  You would essentially have to reimplement sparse arrays to get the same optimizations in your compiled code.
3. `Tr` is not a compilable function.  (Don't ask me why.)  Compiled alternatives that I can think of are not as fast as `Tr` to begin with so the overhead of a MainEvaluate call seems to balance out.  An example alternative to `Tr`:

   ```
   Compile[{{m, _Real, 2}}, Sum[Compile`GetElement[m, i, i], {i, Length @ m}]]
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Compiling to C takes about the same amount of time.    @Mr.Wizard♦